# Gradle multiproject and lib jar directory

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Gradle multi-project build and have to inlcude a JAR file which has to come from a lib directory.

First I had the following structure:

```
- Directory "project"
  - Directory "sub project 1"
    - Directory "lib"
      - File "A.jar"
  - Directory "sub project 2"
```

And the following ´gradle.build´ (only an excerp) for "sub project 1":

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }
}
```

When I compile "sub project 2" I get an error because A.jar cannot be resolved. To solve this I took the following approach:

1: I moved the lib dir in the project root

```
- Directory "project"
  - Directory "sub project 1"
  - Directory "sub project 2"
  - Directory "lib"
    - File "A.jar"
```

2: I defined the lib dir in the ´gradle.build´ for "project" like

```
subprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs '../lib'
        }
    }
}
```

3: I removed the lib dir entry from the ´gradle.build´ for "sub project 1".

Now the question: is this a reasonable approach or if not, what is the recommended way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the projects to declare individual dependencies on the libraries in the `lib` directory, like you would when working with a Maven or Ivy repository, then the approach is fine.